# Geodesic equation with respect to a Riemannian diagonal metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am asked to prove that the differential equations of geodesics on an open set of a pseudoRiemannian manifold $(M, g)$ of dimension $n$ where $g_{ij}=0$ if $i \neq j$ are given by

$$ \frac{d}{ds}(g_{kk}\frac{dx^{k}}{ds})=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i} \frac{\partial g_{ii}}{\partial x^{k}}(\frac{dx^{i}}{ds})^2, 1\leq k \leq n $$

I know that the general formula is given by

$$ \frac{d^{2}x^{k}}{ds^{2}}+ \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \Gamma^{k}_{ij}
 \frac{dx^{i}}{ds} \frac{dx^{j}}{ds})=0, 1\leq k \leq n $$

And I have computed that the non-zero Chrystoffel symbols are:

$$ \Gamma^{k}_{ik} = \frac{1}{2}( \frac{\partial g_{kk}}{\partial x^{i}}) \frac{1}{g_{kk}}$$
$$ \Gamma^{k}_{kj} = \frac{1}{2}( \frac{\partial g_{kk}}{\partial x^{j}}) \frac{1}{g_{kk}} $$
$$ \Gamma^{k}_{jj} = \frac{1}{2}( -\frac{\partial g_{jj}}{\partial x^{k}}) \frac{1}{g_{kk}} $$ or

$$ \Gamma^{k}_{jj} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial g_{jj}}{\partial x^{j}}) \frac{1}{g_{kk}} $$

However, I can't seem to reach the expression I'm asked for from that.

Comment: Your first equation appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed a square. Do you think it holds now?

Comment: Haven’t checked. Is this a homework problem or do you actually need this for something?

Comment: What happens when you do the differentiation on the left side of the first equation?

Comment: It's an assignment. You mean with $g_{kk}$? I had assumed it would be a constant with respect to $s$ (the parameter of the geodesic).

Comment: The metric depends on the point and the point on the curve depends on the parameter.

Comment: Oh, so Leibniz's rule?

Comment: Try to do it and report back how well it works.

Comment: I'm not sure it worked completely, but thanks for the hint

Comment: Did you remember to use the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think I got the global idea but I didn't manage to work it out neatly.